# PHP TextPad Saving Error

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to make a small email subscribers system and I got some help by people and now I 've made it but I got the problems.

Here v in the code I have made a hidden name input and a visible Email input so whenever anyone submits it , it goes like ,Email@email.com which will make it better to Copy all and send emails - anyway This one works 100% on my local host but I tried to upload it to a domain and try it - it goes to the php page and shows me the alert but there is no .txt file created or any txt.

Here is the code : http://pastebin.com/1uE82mZQ

Comment: maybe you don't have permissions to create file?

Comment: Any Idea how to set it? I got a full access to the FTP?

Comment: try var_dump(file_put_contents(...))

Comment: create a folder from FTP, set rights 666 or 777, and save file to this folder

Comment: I have setted the Permissions to 777 to the file but it didn't make any change. also do you mind putting var_dump for me? cuz I don't know how to work with PHP :D..

Comment: var_dump(file_put_contents('subscribers.txt', $_POST['NewsletterName'] . ',' . $_POST['NewsletterEmail'], FILE_APPEND)); and show output

Comment: Okay , I 've did it and a new error appears :(,

http://prntscr.com/7neu44

"bool(false)" I got no idea what is it.


p.s: in localhost it works fine and says (Int)21 or something like this.

Comment: try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php  check permissions, file owner, file path

Comment: also look at web-server logs, there should be an error

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com"; //Sample ftp server
$ftp_user = "foo"; //Sample user
$ftp_pass = "bar"; //Sample pass

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect";
}



$NewsletterName = $_POST['NewsletterName'];
$NewsletterEmail = $_POST['NewsletterEmail'];



$done=fopen('subscribers.txt','w+');
fwrite($done,  $NewsletterName . ',' . $NewsletterEmail);

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Email has been successfully saved!")';
echo '</script>';
fclose($done);  
ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>
```

This is the basic structure!!! You need to do some changes!!! Like the `$ftp_server` `$ftp_user`and `$ftp_pass`

Comment: Thanks and I think that would work but I still got a problem ; I am really newbie in PHP , can you connect this with http://pastebin.com/1uE82mZQ?

-Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $NewsletterName = $_POST['NewsletterName'];
    $NewsletterEmail = $_POST['NewsletterEmail'];



$done=fopen('subscribers.txt','w+');
fwrite($done,  $NewsletterName . ',' . $NewsletterEmail);
fclose($done);

?>
```

Comment: :( Nope - still it doesnt create the file in the FTP.

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.